# Area under period of $\mathrm{a^{csc(x)}}$.

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals, special-functions, trigonometric-integrals

I am trying to find [this graph’s](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dbukj9yhv1) area which was inspired by similar integrals of trigonometric function to the power of trigonometric functions on Math Stack Exchange. I have found the solution with some machine help and this is what cropped up:

$$\mathrm{C(a)=\int_{-\pi}^0 a^{csc(x)}dx=\int_{-\pi}^0 e^{csc(x)ln(a)}dx=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{ln^n(a)}{n!}\int_{-\frac\pi2}^0csc^n(x)dx}$$

Although the expression can be integrated [like this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+csc%5En%28x%29+), the substitution of the bounds fails as for even $n\ge1$, the integral diverges to $\infty$ as an improper integral.

Here is an example area representation of C(e):
[image]

Here is a plot of C(a) with a limit defined maximum at (1,$\pi$) as the integrand for the a=1 case turns, from a limit point of view, into a box like shape with height 1 and length $\pi$. The end behavior is ($\infty$,0) :[image]

I am most interested in the cases of C(2) and C(e). I wish to have an integral with an exact solution, which means write C(a) without approximations nor an integral. This looks like it could use [Bessel functions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Spherical_Hankel_functions) or  [Struve functions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struve_function) as their main integral representation is similar to C(a). Here is why: $$\int_0^1 e^{\cos(\pi x)}dx=1.26606…=I_0(1), \int_0^1 e^{\sin(\pi x)}dx=\text L_0(1)+I_0(1)=1.976309… $$ Integral of exp(tan(x)) [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+exp%28tan%28x%29%29). If I could figure out the integral of exp(csc(x)), then I can evaluate this improper integral. Please correct me and give me feedback!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $\lambda>0$ we have $${\rm C}({\rm e}^\lambda)=\int_{-\pi}^0{\rm e}^{\lambda\csc x}\,{\rm d}x\underset{t=-\csc x}{\phantom{\big[}=\phantom{\big]}}2\int_1^\infty\frac{{\rm e}^{-\lambda t}\,{\rm d}t}{t\sqrt{t^2-1}}=2f(\lambda)$$ and $f'(\lambda)=-K_0(\lambda)$ from an [integral representation](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32.E8) of the modified Bessel function $K_0$.

Hence, using [this formula](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.43.E2) when doing $\int_\lambda^\infty$, one obtains $${\rm C}({\rm e}^\lambda)=\pi-\pi\lambda\big(K_0(\lambda)\mathbf{L}_{-1}(\lambda)+K_1(\lambda)\mathbf{L}_0(\lambda)\big).$$

Here is a [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/gp.html) session for numerical verification (with the default precision):

```
gp > struvel(a,x)=(x/2)^(a+1)*suminf(n=0,(x/2)^(2*n)/gamma(n+3/2)/gamma(n+a+3/2));
gp > foo(a)=Pi*(1-a*(besselk(0,a)*struvel(-1,a)+besselk(1,a)*struvel(0,a)));
gp > goo(a)=foo(a)-2*intnum(x=[1,-1/2],[+oo,a],exp(-a*x)/x/sqrt(x^2-1));
gp > goo(1)
%4 = 1.4987552972984165727 E-37
gp > goo(log(2))
%5 = 1.6750794499217596989 E-37
gp > foo(log(2))
%6 = 0.98349909539743160556395206700695146505
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just come across the [**Sievert Integral**](http://specialfunctionswiki.org/index.php/Sievert_integral):

$$\text S(x,\theta)\mathop=^\text{def}\int_0^\theta e^{-x\sec(t)}dt$$

Since $x$ is a constant variable, we can make $x\to\ln(a)$:

$$\text S(\ln(a),\theta)= \int_0^\theta e^{-\ln(a)\sec(t)}dt=\int_0^\theta a^{-\sec(t)} dt$$

Notice that $$\sec\left(\frac\pi 2-t\right)=\csc(t)\implies t=\frac \pi 2-y\implies dy=-dt,y_1=\frac\pi 2-0=\frac\pi 2,y_2=\frac\pi 2-\theta$$

Therefore:

$$\text S(\ln(a),\theta)= \int_0^\theta a^{-\sec(t)}dt=\int_{\frac\pi 2-\theta}^{\frac\pi 2} \left(\frac1a\right)^{\csc(y)} dy$$

The $\frac1a$ will just shift the function vertically. Our made up $\text C(a)$ function can then be expressed as:

$$\text C\left(\frac1a\right)=2\text S\left(\ln(a),\frac\pi 2\right)=2\int_0^\frac\pi 2 \left(\frac1a\right)^{\csc(y)} dy =2\int_0^\frac\pi 2 \left(\frac1a\right)^{\sec(y)}dy $$

Therefore:

$$\text C(a)=\text S\left(-\ln(a),\frac\pi2\right)$$

Please correct me and give me feedback!