# Finding $\mathrm{\int_{\Bbb R} a^{cosh(x)} dx}$

Tags: trigonometry, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, inverse, hyperbolic-functions

After the success and great answer by @metamorphy of my

> [$$\mathrm{\int_{-\pi}^0 a^{csc(x)}dx}$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4183873/area-under-period-of-mathrmacscx)

question, I experimented a bit more and found this nice [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/3pgssinmx8). This looks almost like a gamma function integral. The summed integral seems to [diverge](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+cosh%5En%28x%29++from+0+to+%E2%88%9E) for. This also used a bit of inverse function magic. Many series for the inverse hyperbolic cosine require the argument$\ \in (-1,1)$. The values of the integral exist even for $a=-1$, $i$, so this value for $a$ would be amazing for finding these results.

$$H(a)\mathop=^\text{def}\mathrm{\int_{-\infty}^\infty a^{cosh(x)}dx=2\int_0^\infty\sqrt{a^{e^{-x}}a^{e^x}}dx=-2ln(a)\int_1^\infty a^t cosh^{-1}(t)dx \\ =2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{ln^n(a)}{n!}\int_0^\infty cosh^n(x)dx=2\int_1^\infty\frac{a^t}{\sqrt{t^2-1}}dt}$$

A non-integral representation is wanted, but a closed form is optional. I will keep working on this problem. Please correct me and give me feedback!

Comment: Compare the last integral to (already used) $\int_1^\infty\frac{{\rm e}^{-\lambda t}\,{\rm d}t}{\sqrt{t^2-1}}=K_0(\lambda)$.

Comment: See also: the Bickley Function [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.43#E2)

Comment: Thanks you for the edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Help from @metamorphy. There seems to be a general strategy when solving a problem with some number to the power of a trigonometric function. Simply use y=trigonometric function (x) and substitute with the result usually being nothing more than a [Bessel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) or [Struve function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/StruveFunction.html). For simplicity, I will not put down the series representation of the function as this one form works best. Using this source from the [highlighted equation](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.43#E12), one can use a Bickley function and simplify:

$$\mathrm{H(a)=\int_\Bbb R a^{cosh(x)}dx=2\int_0^\infty e^{-y\,cosh(t)}dt=2K_0(y)=\boxed{\mathrm{2K_0(-ln(a))}}\implies \int_\Bbb R cos(\pi cosh(x))dx=Re(H(-1))=-\pi Y_0(\pi)=-1.03959318…, H\left(\frac1e\right)=\int_\Bbb R e^{-cosh(x)}dx=2K_0(1)=\quad.8420488764…}$$

Seeing [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fly7rskvyu) plot, one can determine that the function named “H(a)” has the following behavior which still is satisfied by the original value of $\mathrm{H(a)=2K_0(-ln(a))}$. *Still much is left to find on how this analytic continuation works.*

$$\mathrm{0<a<1:H(a)=2K_0(ln(a^{-1})), a>1: H(a)=\int_0^\infty a^{-cosh(x)}dx=2K_0(ln(a))}$$

Here is some [info](https://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselK/16/01/01/) on the Modified Bessel Function of the Second Kind. Just like the reference question, this creates an *analytic continuation* being “able” to take the divergent area for an “a” value and output a complex number. Here is an [amazing complex plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+2besselK%280%2C-ln%28a%2Bb*i%29%29%2C+-4+%3Ca%3C4%2C-4%3Cb%3C4) of the result. [All Bessel functions](https://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/). Please correct me and give me feedback!

Comment: Doesn't $\mathbb{R}$ mean the interval $(-\infty,\infty)$? It seems that you have taken $\mathbb{R}$ to be $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: @RounakSarkar Notice the symmetric integral:$2\int_0^\infty \text{even(x)}dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \text {even(x)}dx$ How did you find the question?

Comment: I was checking your profile, that's how I found this post. Your every question is a treasure of creativity and knowledge. So you might get my comments in some old question of yours in the future.

Comment: @RounakSarkar Thanks, you have some good answers like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4244328/solving-1x10-log-x10-log-x10⋰-frac1-log-x/4244345#4244345) and your $\mathrm{Si^n(x)}$ integral answer.