# Solving $1+x^{10+\log x^{10+\log x^{10+⋰}}}=\frac1{\log x}$

Tags: logarithms

$$\large1+x^{\large10+\large\log x^{\large10+\large\log x^{10+\large ⋰}}}=\frac1{\log x}$$
To solve this equation I used $t=x^{\large10+\large\log x^{\large10+\large\log x^{10+\large ⋰}}}$ . LHS is equal to,
$$1+t=1+x^{10+\log t}$$
$$t=x^{10+\log t}$$
$$\log t=(\log x)\times (10+\log t)$$
$$x=e^{\tfrac{\log t}{10+\log t}}$$
Hence the equation is equivalent to

$$t+1=\frac{10+\log t}{\log t}$$
$$t\log t=10$$

I'm not sure if this helps in solving the equation.

Comment: The equation at the end becomes $t\log t=10$. Can you take it from there?

Comment: @ultralegend5385 I don't know what is the base of the logarithm. If it is in base $10$ we have $t=10$.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it should be base $10$, otherwise we will require Lambert W for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to worry about the base, Let's just take the base to be $b$ then

$t\log_{b}(t)=10$

$\implies t\ln(t)=10\ln(b)$

$\implies W(\ln(t)e^{\ln(t)})=W(10\ln(b))$

$\implies\ln(t)=W(10\ln(b))$

$\implies t=e^{W(10\ln(b))}$

That makes,

$\textstyle\displaystyle{x=e^{\frac{W(10\ln(b))}{10+W(10\ln(b))}}}$