# Closed form of $\int e^{i\csc^2(x)}dx=\int \cos\left(\csc^2(x)\right)dx+i\int \sin\left(\csc^2(x)\right)dx$

Tags: special-functions, closed-form, hypergeometric-function, trigonometric-integrals, fresnel-integrals

This will be an experimental integral with the final result using the [**Kampé de Fériet**](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82818822.pdf) [**function**](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/KampedeFerietFunction.html) with the goal integrals being: $$\int \cos\left(\csc^2(x)\right)dx,\int\sin\left(\csc^2(x)\right)dx\implies \int e^{ i\csc^2(x)}dx=\int\cos\left(\csc^2(x)\right)+i\sin\left(\csc^2(x) \right)dx $$ which already is related to

> [Area under period of $$a^{\csc(x)}$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4183873/area-under-period-of-mathrmacscx)

Here is the method that will be used with term by term integration and a [**Gauss Hypergeometric function**](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/) with 2 constant arguments: $$\int e^{i\csc^2(x)}dx=\int \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{i^n \csc^{2n}(x)}{n!}dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{i^n}{n!}\int\csc^{2n}(x)dx=C-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{i^n}{n!}\cos(x)\sin^2(x)^{n+\frac12}\csc^{2n+1}(x)\,_2\text F_1\left(\frac12,n+\frac12,\frac32,\cos^2(x) \right)$$ Next let’s expand the hypergeometric function as seen in the corresponding bolded link using the [Pochhammer Symbol function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html). Let’s also switch the indices so that we can use the Kampé de Fériet bolded link’s formula more easily:

$$C-\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{i^m}{m!}\cos(x)\sin^2(x)^{m+\frac12}\csc^{2m+1}(x)\,_2\text F_1\left(\frac12,m+\frac12,\frac32,\cos^2(x) \right)=C-\cos(x)\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{i^m}{m!}\sin^2(x)^{m+\frac12}\csc^{2m+1}(x)\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\left(\frac12\right)_n\left(m+\frac12\right)_n \cos^{2n}(x)}{\left(\frac32\right)_nn!}= C-\cos(x)\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{i^m}{m!}\sin^2(x)^{m+\frac12}\csc^{2m+1}(x)\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\left(m+\frac12\right)_n \cos^{2n}(x)}{(2n+1)n!}$$

Now let’s combine sums and leave the Pochhammer Symbols alone until later steps. Let’s not “simplify” because this would constrict the domain:

$$C-\cos(x)\sum_{m=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{i^m}{m!}\sin^2(x)^{m+\frac12}\csc^{2m+1}(x)\frac{\left(\frac12\right)_n\left(m+\frac12\right)_n \cos^{2n}(x)}{\left(\frac32\right)_nn!}= C-\sqrt{\sin^2(x)}\cot(x)\sum_{m=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\left(\frac12\right)_n\left(m+\frac12\right)_n (i\csc^2(x)\sin^2(x))^m\cos^{2n}(x)}{\left(\frac32\right)_nm!n!}  $$

There is a problem as the $\left(m+\frac12\right)_n$ cannot use the Kampé de Fériet function, so we need to do the following:

$$\left(m+\frac12\right)_n =\frac{\Gamma\left(m+n+\frac12\right)}{\Gamma\left(m+\frac12\right)}= \frac{\Gamma\left(m+n+\frac12\right)}{\Gamma\left(m+\frac12\right)} \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac12\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac12\right)}=\frac{\left(\frac12\right)_{m+n}}{\left(\frac12\right)_m}$$

Therefore:

$$ C-\sqrt{\sin^2(x)}\cot(x)\sum_{m=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\left(\frac12\right)_n\left(m+\frac12\right)_n (i\csc^2(x)\sin^2(x))^m\cos^{2n}(x)}{\left(\frac32\right)_nm!n!}=  C-\sqrt{\sin^2(x)}\cot(x)\sum_{m=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\left(\frac12\right)_{m+n}\left(\frac12\right)_n(i\csc^2(x)\sin^2(x))^m\cos^{2n}(x)}{\left(\frac12\right)_m\left(\frac32\right)_nm!n!}   $$

When the Kampé de Fériet function is defined as:

$$\text F^{p,r,u}_{q,s,v}\left(^{a_1,…,a_p;c_1,…,c_r;f_1,…,f_u}_{b_1,…,b_q;d_1,…,d_s;g_1,…,g_v}\ x,y\right)\mathop=^\text{def}\sum_{m=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\prod\limits_{j=1}^p(a_j)_{m+n} \prod\limits_{j=1}^r(c_j)_m \prod\limits_{j=1}^u (f_j)_n x^my^n}{\prod\limits_{j=1}^q (b_j)_{m+n} \prod\limits_{j=1}^s(d_j)_m \prod\limits_{j=1}^v(g_j)_n m!n!}$$

Therefore:

$$\int e^{ i\csc^2(x)}dx=C-\sqrt{\sin^2(x)}\cot(x)\sum_{m=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\left(\frac12\right)_{m+n}\left(\frac12\right)_n(i\csc^2(x)\sin^2(x))^m\cos^{2n}(x)}{\left(\frac12\right)_m\left(\frac32\right)_nm!n!}= C-\sqrt{\sin^2(x)}\cot(x)\text F^{1,0,1}_{0,1,1}\left(^{\frac12;;\frac12}_{;\frac12;\frac32}\ i\csc^2(x)\sin^2(x),\cos^2(x)\right) $$

which is a closed form in terms of a fairly common hypergeometric function and [sign](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function) function. The problem is that this function only has $p,q,r,s,u,v$ values of $0,1$, so we can probably simplify the Kampé de Fériet function in terms of simpler functions like how with the following [**Normalized Fresnel Integral functions**](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/FresnelS/introductions/FresnelIntegrals/):

$$\int_0^\pi \cos(\csc^2(x))dx=\pi\left(1-\text C\left(\sqrt{\frac2\pi}\right)- \text S\left(\sqrt{\frac2\pi}\right)\right)=0.09655932…:$$

[image]

or

$$\int_0^\pi \sin(\csc^2(x))dx=\pi\left(\text C\left(\sqrt{\frac2\pi}\right)- \text S\left(\sqrt{\frac2\pi}\right)\right)=1.48957873…:$$

[image]

which can also be written in terms of [Error functions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function). So how can we write

$$\int e^{i\csc^2(x)}dx=\int \cos\left(\csc^2(x) \right)dx+i\int \sin\left(\csc^2(x) \right)dx=  C-\sqrt{\sin^2(x)}\cot(x)\text F^{1,0,1}_{0,1,1}\left(^{\frac12;;\frac12}_{;\frac12;\frac32}\ i\csc^2(x)\sin^2(x),\cos^2(x)\right)\mathop=^{0\ne x\in\Bbb R}  C-\text{sgn}(\sin(x))\cos(x)\text F^{1,0,1}_{0,1,1}\left(^{\frac12;-;\frac12}_{-;\frac12;\frac32}\ i,\cos^2(x)\right) $$

in another closed form via less general functions? A solution verification is also requested. Please correct me and give me feedback!

Comment: Why do I get the feeling that you are just posting your daily notebook each day with an arbitrary question attached?

Comment: @DecarbonatedOdes These are just problems that seem interesting. Do you have any ideas on how to simplify?

Comment: No, but I do believe a lot of integral and series problems here on SE revolve around the generalization of $ (\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} g(k) )^s $ , $ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} g^s(k) $ , or $ f(f(x)) $. The last one, of course, would fall into the second category as well.

Comment: @DecarbonatedOdes How would this generation apply in this case?

Comment: With some rough experimentation, it may be an [Owen T function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Owen%27s_T_function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Owen T function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Owen%27s_T_function) is used for statistics, but has applications like the following definition:

$$2\pi \cdot\text T(x,a)\mathop=^\text{def} \int_0^a\frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}2\left(t^2+1\right)}}{t^2+1}dt$$

We can easily use a series expansion for the exponential function with index $n$, but that would case a hypergeometric function with a negative argument index of $-n$ which cannot really be converted into $n$ in the function. This problem is due to the positive exponent in the $e^y$, it is better to do the following substitution to shape make it easier to turn into a  Kampé de Feriét function. We just need an identity, so keep in mind possible restrictions:

$$\int_0^a\frac{e^{-x^2\left(t^2+1\right)}}{t^2+1}dt\ \mathop=^{t^2+1=\frac1{u^2+1}\implies t=\pm \sqrt{\frac1{u^2+1}-1}}_{dt=\frac i{(u^2+1)^\frac32}du,u>0}\ i\int_0^{\sqrt{-\frac{a^2}{a^2+1}}} (u^2+1)\frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{u^2+1}}}{(u^2+1)^\frac32}du=i\int_0^{\sqrt{-\frac{a^2}{a^2+1}}} \frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{u^2+1}}}{(u^2+1)^\frac12}du=i\int_0^{\sqrt{-\frac{a^2}{a^2+1}}} \sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^mx^{2m}}{m!(u^2+1)^m(u^2+1)^\frac12}du=i \sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^mx^{2m}}{m!}\int_0^{b} (u^2+1)^{-m-\frac12}du$$

The upper bound will be called $b$ by definition. Let there be an integration using a [Gauss hypergeometric series](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/02/01/) and [Pochhammer symbol](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html):

$$i \sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^mx^{2m}}{m!}\int_0^b (u^2+1)^{-m-\frac12}du=i \sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^mx^{2m}}{m!}b\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\left(\frac12\right)_n \left(m+\frac12\right)_n(-b^2)^n}{\left(\frac32\right)_n n!}$$

Notice the similar coefficients to the original problem. We can change the pochhammer symbol by:

$$\left(m+\frac12\right)_n =\frac{\Gamma\left(m+n+\frac12\right)\Gamma\left(\frac12\right)}{\Gamma\left(m+\frac12\right)\Gamma\left(\frac12\right)}=\frac{\left(\frac12\right)_{m+n}}{\left(\frac12\right)_m}$$

Therefore we can use the question’s Kampé de Feriét function link:

$$i \sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^mx^{2m}}{m!}b\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\left(\frac12\right)_n \left(m+\frac12\right)_n(-b^2)^n}{\left(\frac32\right)_n n!}=ib \sum_{m=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\left(\frac12\right)_{m+n}\left(\frac12\right)_n \left(-x^2\right)^m\left(-b^2\right)^n}{\left(\frac12\right)_m\left(\frac32\right)_n m!n!}=i b\,\text F^{1,0,1}_{0,1,1}\left(^{\frac12;;\frac12}_{;\frac12;\frac32}\ -x^2,-b^2\right)$$

which we now need to form into:

$$\int e^{i\csc^2(x)}dx=\int \cos\left(\csc^2(x) \right)dx+i\int \sin\left(\csc^2(x) \right)dx=  C-\sqrt{\sin^2(x)}\cot(x)\text F^{1,0,1}_{0,1,1}\left(^{\frac12;;\frac12}_{;\frac12;\frac32}\ i\csc^2(x)\sin^2(x),\cos^2(x)\right)=$$

To finish the answer, let’s calculate $b$:

$$b={\sqrt{-\frac{a^2}{a^2+1}}}\implies -b^2=\frac{a^2}{a^2+1}$$

Therefore:

$$\text T(x,a)=-\frac{{\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{a^2+1}}}}{2\pi}\,\text F^{1,0,1}_{0,1,1}\left(^{\frac12;;\frac12}_{;\frac12;\frac32}\ -x^2,\frac{a^2}{a^2+1}\right)$$

Solving for $a,x$ and taking the positive square root branch gives the final answer as:

$$\int e^{i\csc^2(x)}dx=\int \cos\left(\csc^2(x) \right)dx+i\int \sin\left(\csc^2(x) \right)dx= -2\pi \sqrt{\cot^2(x)}\tan(x)\text T\left(1-i,\sqrt{\cot^2(x)}\right)+C\mathop=^{x\in\Bbb R} -2\pi\text{sgn}(\cot(x))\text T\left(1-i,|\cot(x)|\right)+C$$

Here is proof of the result with [**this computation**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=fullsimplify+ddx+-2pi+sqrt%28cot%5E2%28x%29%29+tan%28x%29+OwenT%5B1-i%2Csqrt%28cot%5E2%28x%29%29%5D)

Therefore one special case is with the [Imaginary Error function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erfi.html) and [Fresnel Integrals](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral):

$$\int_0^\frac\pi4 e^{i\csc^2(x)}dx= \int_0^\frac\pi2 e^{i\csc^2(x)}dx -\int_\frac\pi4^\frac\pi2 e^{i\csc^2(x)}dx =\int_0^1 \frac{e^{i(x^2+1)}}{x^2+1}dx=2\pi(\text T(1-i,\infty)-\text T(1-i,1))=\frac\pi2+\frac\pi2\left((i-1)\text C\left(\sqrt{\frac2\pi}\right)-(1+i) \text S\left(\sqrt{\frac2\pi}\right)\right)+\frac\pi 4\left(\text{erfi}^2\left(\sqrt[4]{-1}\right)+1\right) $$

Note that the following code also applies with the [Complementery Error function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erfc.html):

`π/2 + 1/2 ((-1 + i) π C(sqrt(2/π)) - (1 + i) π S(sqrt(2/π))) = π/2 + 1/2 (-(1 + i) π (1/2 + 1/4 (1 + i) (i erfc(1/2 (1 - i) sqrt(π) sqrt(2/π)) - erfc(1/2 (1 + i) sqrt(π) sqrt(2/π)))) + (-1 + i) π (1/2 - 1/4 (1 - i) (i erfc(1/2 (1 - i) sqrt(π) sqrt(2/π)) + erfc(1/2 (1 + i) sqrt(π) sqrt(2/π)))))`

Here is a plot of the real, cosine, part:

[image]

Here is a plot of the imaginary, sine, part:

[image]
Please correct me and give me feedback!

It is hard to separate real and imaginary parts of the OwenT function unless you use [Complex Components](https://functions.wolfram.com/ComplexComponents/)

Comment: The derivation had one small mistake, but the result is correct.