# $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^\frac{(5+\sqrt3i)n}6x^n}{n!}(\frac ns )^{(n-1)}\,_2\text F_1\left(1-n,-sn;2-sn;s\right)$ closed form or integral.

Tags: indefinite-integrals, closed-form, inverse-function, hypergeometric-function, analytic-continuation

**From:**

> [Completing the explicit $\lim\limits_{c\to0}\text I^{-1}_{cx}(r,c)$/ inverse $\int_0^x\frac{t^{r-1}}{1-t}dt,r\in\Bbb Q$ series expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4566160/completing-the-explicit-lim-limits-c-to0-text-i-1-cxr-c-inverse-i)

here is a [Lagrange inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem) expansion with $r=\frac23$ using [**inverse beta regularized $\text I^{-1}_x(a,b)$**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseBetaRegularized.html), [**factorial power $u^{(v)}$**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=factorialpower), the [Gauss hypergeometric function $_2\text F_1(a,b;c;z)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=2F1), and the [**principal root**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=principal+root): $$\begin{align}f(x)=\int_0^x \frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]x(1-x)}\implies f^{-1}(x)=\lim_{c\to0}\text I^{-1}_{cx}\left(\frac23,c\right)=\left(1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\left(-e^{-x}\right)^n}{n!}\lim_{x\to1}\frac{d^{n-1}(\sqrt[3]{-1}x+1)^{\sqrt[3]{-1}n}\left(1-(-1)^\frac23x\right)^{-(-1)^\frac23n}}{dx^{n-1}}\right)^3\end{align}$$

to get:

$$\begin{align}\left(1+\sqrt3\sum_{2\ne n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^\frac{(5+\sqrt3i)n+1}6e^{-nx}}{n!}(\sqrt[-3]{-1}n)^{(n-1)}\,_2\text F_1\left(1-n,-\sqrt[3]{-1}n;2-\sqrt[3]{-1}n;\sqrt[3]{-1}\right)\right)^3=\left(1-\sqrt3\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^b\frac{(-1)^\frac{7n-2m+5}6e^{-\left(\frac{\sqrt3}6\pi+x\right)n}\left(\sqrt[3]{-1}n\right)!\left(\sqrt[-3]{-1}\right)!}{\left((-1)^\frac23n+m+1\right)!\left(\sqrt[-3]{-1}n-m\right)!\Gamma(n-m)m!n}\right)^3\end{align}\tag1$$ The possibly hypergometric [**double**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=beta%28%281-sqrt%283%29sum%5Bsum%5B%28%28%28-1%29%5E%28n%2B1%2F6++%285+-+2+m+%2B+n%29+%29exp%28-n%28%E2%88%9A3%2F6%CF%80%2B1.64%29%29%29%28%28-1%29%5E%281%2F3%29n%29%21%28-%28-1%29%5E%282%2F3%29n%29%21%29%2F%28n+m%21+%CE%93%5B-m%2Bn%5D+%281%2Bm-n%2B%28-1%29%5E%281%2F3%29+n%29%21+%28-m-%28-1%29%5E%282%2F3%29+n%29%21%29%2C%7Bm%2C0.0%2C15.0%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1.0%2C10.0%7D%5D%29%5E3%2C2%2F3%2C0%29) [**sum**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=inversebetaregularized%280.00001+x%2C2%2F3%2C0.00001%29-%281%2Bsum%5B%E2%88%9A3+%28-1%29%5E%28%28%285%2B%E2%88%9A3+i%29n%2B1%29%2F6%29+e%5E%28-n+x%29%2Fn%21+factorialpower%28%28-1%29%5E%28-1%2F3%29n%2Cn-1%292F1%281-n%2C-%28-1%29%5E%281%2F3%29n%2C2-%28-1%29%5E%281%2F3%29n%2C%28-1%29%5E%281%2F3%29%29%2C%7Bn%2C1.0%2C28.0%7D%5D%29%5E3%2Cx%3D2%2F5) has an empty $n=2$ term, likely $b\ge n-1$, and interchangeable sums. This sum is an analytic continuation of $\lim\limits_{c\to0}\text I^{-1}_{cx}\left(\frac23,0\right), x\ge0$ since it inverts $f(x)$ for complex inputs too. It implies $y\ge0$ and a period of $2\pi$ for $y$.

Unfortunately, [standard double hypergeometric](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4303684/closed-form-of-int-ei-csc2xdx-int-cos-left-csc2x-rightdxi-int-s) functions fail since they require coefficients of $m,n$, as gamma function arguments, [to be integers](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=horn+function). Additionally, the Gauss hypergeometric function [**integral representations**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=integral+representation+2F1%281-n%2C-%28-1%29%5E%281%2F3%29n%2C2-%28-1%29%5E%281%2F3%29n%2C%28-1%29%5E%281%2F3%29%29) converge for $n<0$. Therefore, none of these probably help get an integral representation or closed form of $\lim\limits_{c\to0}\text I^{-1}_{cx}\left(\frac23,0\right)$

Also, the hypergeometric part fits $_2\text F_1(a,b;b+2,z)$, but there is no [special case formula](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/03/06/) for it.

**An equivalent definition is:**

$$e^{\sqrt3y}\cos(y)=x\implies y=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2\sqrt[3]{\lim\limits_{c\to0}\text I^{-1}_{c\left(\frac\pi{\sqrt3}-\ln(2x)\right)}\left(\frac23,c\right)}+1}{\sqrt3}\right)+\frac\pi6, 0\le x\le\frac{e^\frac\pi{\sqrt3}}2$$ [Shown here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=khinchin-exp%28sqrt%283%29x%29cos%28x%29%2Cx%3Dpi%2F6%2B+tan%5E%28-1%29%28%281+%2B+%288+InverseBetaRegularized%280.00001%28%CF%80%2Fsqrt%283%29+-+log%282+khinchin%29%29%2C+2%2F3%2C+0.00001%29%29%5E%281%2F3%29%29%2Fsqrt%283%29%29+), but maybe it is extendible outside the restriction.

Is there any closed form or integral representation for $(1)$?

Comment: There is a closed form in terms of $\text I^{-1}_s\left(\frac13,\frac23\right)$ or with flipped parameters